# Issues with nesting CSS divs/boxes and overflow

Tags: css, html, overflow

Hi I'm just wondering if anyone can help me out. I'm new enough to web design, and I'm having some problems with my CSS.

Basically I cant figure out how to correctly nest my divs/boxes without having overflow issues! I have tried using `overflow: hidden;` but this still hasn't worked, I've also tried floating the child elements either left or right to see if it would help but still no luck!

My css looks like this:

```
#customerReg {
    width: 47%;
    height: 480px;
    float: left;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}    

#customerInfo {
    width: 95%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #414141;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#participantReg {
    width: 47%;
    height: 480px;
    float: right;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

#participantInfo {
    width: 95%;
    height: 120px;
    background: #414141;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

My HTML Is as follows:

```
<div class="contentbody" style="border:#FF0066 solid 2px;">

    <div id="customerReg" style="border:#33CC00 solid 2px">
    <div id="customerInfo">
      <p>Customer Registration

      </p>
    </div>

    <!-- End of customerReg --></div>

    <div id="participantReg" style="border:#33CC00 solid 2px">
        <div id="participantInfo">
          <p>Participant Sign Up</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>

    <!-- End of participantReg --></div>


    <!-- end .contentbody --></div>
```

What im aiming for is so have two rounded boxes side by side with two smaller boxes inside these boxes. I tried to post an image but it wouldnt let me! What im getting is that the two inner boxes are both spilling out on the right side of the outer boxes if that makes sense??

Can anyone tell me where im going wrong and what i can do to correct this as ive spent hours trying to find an answer and cant figure it out!

Comment: I've tried to replicate and can't.  setup an example on http://jsfiddle.net that causes the issue so we can see whats going on

Answer (score 1):

The parent div set:

- overflow: hidden;

*OR*

```
 #customerReg, #participantReg{
     float:left;
 }

 .contentbody:after{
    content: '.';
    clear:both;
    visibility: hidden;
    *zoom:1;
    height:0;
    display:block;
 }
```

Comment: Overflow: hidden; isnt solving the problem.

Ive also tried the CSS cahnges for .contentbody that you have suggested and still no change!??

Comment: I had a typo I used #customerReg twice instead of improved answer!  Make sure .contentbody:after lies at the end of your stylesheet.  If you are using IE maybe included modernizr so the :after psudeo is avalabile.

Comment: I have tried setting both boxes to float:left; and have tried putting the .contentbody:after at the end of my internal and external styling and still nothing? Im using firefox.

Comment: I dont see what your problem is then, unless its a syntax error. Result: http://jsfiddle.net/GRB3r/ Also the widths could be too large for the container

Comment: If you look at the fiddle below posted by Preston that will show you what im aiming for, but for some reason my inner boxes are spilling over on the right habd side and nothing i do seems to fix this, i have tried changing the widths but then im not getting the look that im going for?

Answer (score 0):

if you set the width of the first `div` the boxes ar side by side:

look this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VxFQn/)

`.contentbody{
  width:990px;
  border:#FF0066 solid 2px;
}`

Comment: Thats not the issue the OP is having.  I can get the same result as you if I widen the frame without setting the width. He is stating the inner grey boxes are spilling out of the green bordered area.

Comment: @Henesnarfel im not too sure how to use jsfiddle to show my problem, i tried entering my code but it didnt display the problem i was having, it showed one box ontop of teh other! im using dreamweaver and have been working on a liquid template if that makes a difference? Yes as stated above the inner boxes are spilling out of the outter boxes but only to the right in both cases! Preston the fiddle you made is how i want it to look but this isnt what im getting!

Comment: try to copy and paste the css on jsfiddle in your project... can you provide some link with your problem?